# How to set chips edittext as editable text in android

Tags: android, android-chips

[image: chips edittext]

I am using library [eyeem/chips-android](https://github.com/eyeem/chips-android)

I would like to be able to edit the text in a chip.

I am new to android, so I am unable to understand the  ChipsEditText java file.

Comment: First: asterisks don't make headers in your post. Second: the chips are actually compound drawables, so you can't simply edit the text in them without removing it, then adding its string content to the EditText, then setting the cursor position in the EditText

Comment: First of all thanks for the comment cricket_007, But I don't know how to revert back from drawables to EditText, and I don't know how to use the library, So please help..

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you don't know Android to read the code in the library. To get the text of a chip, you can do `ChipsEditText.getLayoutBuild().text`. Might need to add `toString` on that, but you'll need to figure out how to get the chip that you want to edit first

Comment: Please check out my answer and code sample : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52007466/5439116