# Android material chip component crashing app. Unable to inflate xml

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-components, android-chips, material-components-android

Tried **Chip** component from both support library
     `com.google.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01` and material
     `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01`

**StackTrace**

> ```
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Binary XML file 
>       line #72: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip 
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)`
> ```

**Layout**

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    style="style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/account"
    app:closeIconEnabled="true" />`
```

Comment: Did you tried with `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'`

Comment: Yes i did. Same issue

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Are you extending on of the provided themes as explained in  https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/?

Comment: @Paranoid42 thanks for the info.. Actually I didn't do that. Will get back after checking.

Comment: @Paranoid42 Thanks man it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Update your app theme to inherit from one of these themes:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
```

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

> Note: Using a Material Components theme enables a custom view inflater

Source:
https://www.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Comment: I was wondering why any of `com.google.android.material` widget is not inflating in the app. This is the reason!

Comment: In my case, `val chip = new Chip(context)` and `val chip = layoutInflater.from(context).inflate` were both failing despite my material theme. This is because I passed the wrong `context` (application context instead of activity context). Therefore, my material theme wasn't yet applied.

Comment: *.Bridge is better for most cases. "If you use a bridge theme, you can start using Material Design components without changing your app theme" https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started#bridge-themes

Comment: @ZhouHongbo, I changed `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge` and an application crashed. :-)

Answer (score 82):

You can juste add @style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light style attribut in xml layout like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="chip"
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm without changing the App Theme attribute.

Comment: getting The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

Answer (score 5):

Add the following new theme attributes to your existing app theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

    <!-- Original AppCompat attributes. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_app_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_app_primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_app_accent_color</item>

    <!-- New MaterialComponents attributes. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="scrimBackground">@color/mtrl_scrim_color</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline2</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline4">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline5">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline6">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceBody2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceOverline">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Overline</item>

</style>
```

Source: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/
Thanks @Paranoid42

Comment: Yes initially that was the problem.. I was using appcompat theme

Comment: Adding these shows a black screen when using the chip but doesnt crash atleast

Answer (score 4):

**Finally Got a solution as how to generate chips dynamically using new material chips**

Google has not provided any documentation for chipsInput layout or how to make a gmail address like layout. Using ChipDrawable won't give delete operation on chip option as can't call setOnCloseIconClickListener. I was able to do using HorizontalScrollView, ChipGroup and EditText

Here's my code sample :

[MaterialChipsInputDemo](https://github.com/sourin00/MaterialChipsInputDemo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Theme.MaterialComponents.**.Bridge` to replace your previous theme.

For example, if the old theme is `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar`, the new theme will be `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge`.

See https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started#bridge-themes