# Material chip crashing app. Cannot inflate xml

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

My app crashes when trying to inflate the `com.google.android.material.chip.Chip`class.

The dependency i am using is `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Here is my XML code

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chipActive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Active"/>
```

The error I get is

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
```

I found a question similar to mine on another thread but there was no solution there that was helpful to me. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this issue please help me :D

Comment: What is line number #18 in your layout

Comment: Update your app theme to inherit from one of these themes as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877777/android-material-chip-component-crashing-app-unable-to-inflate-xml

Comment: You'll need to change your main **app theme to Material bridge themes**.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution just after posting this question. I updated the dependency to `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'` and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use Theme `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in the chip

> android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"