# Application crashes on loading android chip component

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

Chip material component crash

I'm using android.support.design.chip.Chip material element using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 support library. App crashes with this error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #130: Binary XML file line #130: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #130: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.chip.Chip" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.m22_3.pilotapp-Em4FGoATeSyeWoDIACtXXA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
```

I have already tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314889/9938652) and replaced my theme parent with these:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge
```

but still have that crash. I also Migrated to AndroidX but still no chance.
App gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.m22_3.pilotapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.0.0'


    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.9'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.9'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.9'

    implementation 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    }
```

Project's gradle file:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } //https://jitpack.io or https://maven.google.com
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

XML code:

```
<CoodrdinateLayout>....<LinearLayout>.... <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filter_linear_layout_detailAc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cornered2_stroked_tab2color"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/filter_chip_detailAc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cornered_filled_tab2color"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/filter"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:chipIcon="@drawable/filter"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="false"
                    app:singleLine="true" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/location_filter_chip_detailAc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                    app:singleLine="true" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/experience_filter_chip_detailAc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                    app:singleLine="true" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/timeInterval_filter_chip_detailAc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                    app:singleLine="true" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/industry_filter_chip_detailAc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                    app:singleLine="true" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/partFullTime_filter_chip_detailAc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                    app:singleLine="true" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/blueWhiteCollar_filter_chip_detailAc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                    app:singleLine="true" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Have you added `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0''` ?. If not then add it to your gradle.

Comment: Add your code and gradle dependencies also .

Comment: I tried it. no luck. Added my dependencies and code.

Comment: try clean and build your project.

Comment: also you have repetitive appcompat dependences, keep the latest version.

Comment: cleaning/invalidating cache didn't  work.

Comment: Thanks I saw the repetetive line: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'` and removed it. Now it gives me "cannot resolve R" and can't build the project

Comment: Ok I found the problem. In first chip I have set a background: `android:background="@drawable/cornered_filled_tab2color"` while chips apparently decide their background and this caused the crash. thanks everyone.