# How to fix "Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip" (with custom style) for android 6.0 (API 23)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-chips

I am using material chips into my project. Almost every android version shows no problem with it but android 6.0 (marshmallow - API 23). Actually material chips can't be inflated for this android version and crashes every time.

I have tried following things:

- Already updated the theme from style with `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`
- Checked solution with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877777/android-material-chip-component-crashing-app-unable-to-inflate-xml)
- Created `layout-v23` to show different layout for marshmallow os (API 23)

I am using this `chipTheme` from the `style.xml`

```
<style name="chipTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@drawable/bg_chip_text_state_list</item>
        <item name="chipCornerRadius">10dp</item>
        <item name="chipStrokeColor">#D9D9D9</item>
        <item name="chipStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:checkable">true</item>
        <item name="chipIconVisible">false</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>

// into layout

   <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/filter_cat_1"
                style="@style/chipTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/chipTextAppearance"/>
```

I expect to show the same chips with the same custom style into all version of android (API 16 to API 28+). How can I do it?

Comment: Have you migrated to androidx?

Comment: Yes, why? @SumitShukla