# MaterialCardView crashes with material:1.1.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, material-components-android, material-components

I am using MaterialCardView as my `cardview` layout. Now, Android-studio started showing me that instead of current  `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"`, I should update to `1.1.0`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

  <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
      app:cardElevation="8dp">

      <...more layout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

with 1.1.0, I am getting crash `Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`

So, I have 3 cases:

1. stick to `1.0.0` and use `MaterialCardView` (working, but not preferred)
2. Update to `1.1.0` (or 1.2.0-alpha) and use `androidx.CardView` (working, but not preferred)
3. Update to `1.1.0` and change the `MaterialCardView` (**preferred, but not working**)

Since I want to go with option #3, and I don't have any solution, can anybody give a clue?

**Update**
My style (I have style & style-night also. Here I am posting the `style` only):

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme">
    <!-- Color of text and icon when SELECTED -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <!-- Background color when SELECTED -->
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>

  </style>

</resources>
```

And here is the error(from **Logcat**)

```
2020-02-12 13:34:18.171 12562-12562/com.example.phocast E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.phocast, PID: 12562
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.phocast:layout/fragment_place: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.phocast:layout/fragment_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.phocast:layout/fragment_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.example.phocast.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:555)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4137)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:383)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:219)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:64)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:207)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:81)
        at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.<init>(MaterialCardView.java:124)
        at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.<init>(MaterialCardView.java:114)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481) 
        at com.example.phocast.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:555) 
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4137) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:383) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:219) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:64) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:207) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2020-02-12 13:34:18.620 12562-12584/com.example.phocast I/example.phocas: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 110384(4259KB) AllocSpace objects, 46(1212KB) LOS objects, 41% free, 7792KB/12MB, paused 1.092ms total 150.548ms
2020-02-12 13:34:18.692 12562-12562/com.example.phocast I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12562 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you add details of `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` in your layout and also include the error log?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick replay. The error log is not very helpful, as it just says can not inflate binary xml file.

Comment: Then can you add your full xml?

Comment: Post your full XML file and Build,gradle file here in : https://paste.ofcode.org/

Comment: try to add and check : android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" in XML in com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView , https://www.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/ and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314889/3974530

Comment: Post your app theme and the full stacktrace.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti my style (I guess by theme, you meant the style.xml), logcat and app level gradel added.

Comment: @BaRud The issue is reported in the stacktrace. Check the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60183892/2016562)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

you can just keep it in your materialcardview itself also:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
     **** android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"  *****
      app:cardElevation="8dp">
```

Comment: Or you can use the desired solution for who's creating a new app as suggested in [DeepLathia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61477087/4367683).

Answer (score 28):

The error is in the stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

With the version 1.1.0 you have to inherit from a [`Theme.MaterialComponents`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).

Change your app theme to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
  <!-- ....  -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working, except the fact that the active font color of `tablayout` has changed its colour (from white to violet), I guess as an artefact of transition from AppCompat to MaterialsTheme.  I havn't set that font color explicitly. Given, this is beyond the scope of the current question,  I will create a new issue. Will you mind if I tag that to you here?

Comment: @BaRud. Thanks, no problem.

Answer (score 15):

You need to change your AppTheme to have it's parent theme as a descendant of **MaterialComponent**

In your particular case changing the AppTheme from

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
```

to

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Exactly! Forgot to change theme of new app ) thank you

Comment: Adding MaterialComponents in App theme solved my error thank you!

Answer (score 11):

In my case I just added the **android:theme=""** attribute and it worked. My Material Card View element is as below -

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/edit_profile_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_10"
            **android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"**
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp_20"
            app:state_dragged="false">

           ....
           ....

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

try latest version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

in your xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works after changing this `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight>` to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your theme in style.xml to:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">`

it will work

Answer (score 0):

If after changing the theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents` in the *styles.xml* didn't work then make sure you have added *style* tag in the *MaterialCard*.

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
```

Comment: i tried your answer i still get the same error. Is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the previous theme of your application (AppCompat) you can use a Bridge theme.
They are described [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started)

From the documentation:

> Bridge themes inherit from AppCompat themes, but also define the new Material Components theme attributes for you. If you use a bridge theme, you can start using Material Design components without changing your app theme.

For instance in `res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error in newest material design version. I just remove inappropriate colors( `app:strokeColor="?attr/colorSurfaceVariant"`) in resources and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For `material3` style use `android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight"`. i.e.

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_card"*
        **style="@style/Widget.Material3.CardView.Outlined"**
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_10"
        **android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight"**
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp_20"
        app:state_dragged="false">

       ....
       ....

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

or in theme use

```
<style name="Base.Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
```

or for `NoActionBar` case:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```