# How to set chipBackgroundColor via "android:theme" attribute with an AppCompat app theme

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat, material-components, android-chips

I have a `ChipGroup` that has one `Chip` item :

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chip_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/DarkThemeTag"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tag_text_dimen"
                app:chipIcon="@null"
                app:chipIconEnabled="false"/>
```

As you can notice I set the `DarkThemeTag` theme on the `ChipGroup`.

```
<style name="DarkThemeTag" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/tag_chip_dark_checkable</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

My app theme inherits from `AppCompat`, not from `MaterialComponents`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      ....
    </style>
```

According to [Chip official page](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) it inherits from `MaterialComponents`.
[@Mikail Sharin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877777/android-material-chip-component-crashing-app-unable-to-inflate-xml) says that app's theme should inherit from `MaterialComponents`.
In [this](https://www.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/#bridge-themes) article is stated that if you can't change your app to inherit from `MaterialComponents` and you want to stick to `AppCompat` you should use one of the **Bridge Themes**, so that's what I did.

The problem is that the `chipBackgroundColor` attribute does not apply to ChipGroup's children. The  `android:textColor` does however.

Do you guys have any ideea what can be wrong?

Note:If I apply the same style on the `Chip` element it works

Comment: Apply a bridge theme in your app != to use android:theme in a widget.

Comment: Understood. I don't understand tho, why Chips work fine with an AppCompat theme, but when I try to set the "chipBackgroundColor" attribute for example, it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a **Bridge theme in your app**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

You can use the `android:theme` in a widget **to override some attributes** like colors not to apply a style:

```
      <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:theme="@style/DarkThemeTag"
            ..>
```

with:

```
<style name="DarkThemeTag" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then you can apply a **custom style** in widget as:

```
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/my_chip"
            ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="my_chip" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
   <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/tag_chip_dark_checkable</item>
</style>
```

or you can simply apply it in your layout:

```
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            app:chipBackgroundColor="....."
            ../>
```

If you want to **override** the chip background color using `android:theme` you should use:

```
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:theme="@style/custom_color"
            ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="custom_color" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">....</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">....</item>
</style>
```

since the default selector in the `chipBackgroundColor` uses these colors.